# Can not sign in to the rails console for controller integration testing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Right now I am trying to access the rails console in development mood to test integration of controllers.

What I am doing right now is kind of,

```
>> ApplicationController.allow_forgery_protection = false
>> app.post('/users/sign_in', {'user'=> {'username' => 'sudo' , 
   'password' => 'sudo'}})
=> 200
>> app.get('/labels')
```

after visiting the authorized link, its showing 401 and redirecting with 302 status.

So, what is wrong I am doing here?

Comment: does the `sign_in` really work? if the username or password not match, it still might return 200 as response.

Answer (score 0):

I have test it in my rails console, rails 4.2.1. It's working. So i suggest that you can check the `app.response.body` and `app.session` after send the `sign_in` request, check if really success.